# Is it possible to tether internet between my android phone and a 3G HSPDA router?

Tags: android, 3g, tether

I wish to share my 3G connection with a router using my current android phone without having to buy a new sim card or a dongle of some sort. Is this possible? I am able to tether my phone making it a wifi hotspot but what I want is to only share the internet with a router.

The reason I ask is because I have a small Ubuntu PC in my car (mini ATX) which I want to access from a android tablet. To be able to do this I need the tablet and the PC connected to a router so that I can forward port 5900 and use remote desktop. I also want internet whilst using remote desktop, thus I need the router to have and internet connection.

This is a schematic of what I want to achieve:

```
                        ?                |--> android pad
3G Internet from Phone <--> 3G Router <--|
                                         |--> PC
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So after some more research the answer seems to be this product:

http://www.edimax.co.uk/en/produce_detail.php?pd_id=352&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=77

As it says in the description:

> Internet tethering via iPhone, HTC,
>   Blackberry, Nokia, Sony Ericsson, and
>   other smart phone

It is a neat little thing as it comes with a battery and also runs of a micro USB connection. Perfect for my car setup.